# Inputs with different length in MATLAB Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Let's assume that I want to create a feedforward NN in MATLAB for a system with two different types of input parameters with different length. The first input is a vector of size 10, and the second input is a scalar value. Assume that I have 1000 of these input parameters. The output is a scalar:

**Inputs**: 1000 (samples) of {[1,10] first input , [1,1] second input}

**Output**: 1000 (samples) of [1,1]

Comment: Maybe you could convert all inputs to [1, 10]. For input [1, 1] you need to fill 9 position with some filler value. If you don't observe at your dataset 0, you can fill 9 places with 0 or -1. Or maybe I don't get it right and you have 1000x[1, 10] and 1000x[1, 1], in such case, you can create 1000x[1, 11] and feed the network.

Comment: @viceriel: thanks, as I said in my question, I have input parameters of different length: a scalar and a vector of length 10. Then I have 1000 samples of that combination. If you assume cell array, then I have 1000 cell array in which every cell has two parameters of length 1 and 10.